# How deploy webapp to Azure from command line

Tags: azure, msbuild, visual-studio-2019

I have a project https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/tree/master/Samples
which is deployed to Azure via Visual Studio 2019
How can I strip it through the command line?
when i executing this command
"C: \ Program Files (x86) \ Microsoft Visual Studio \ 2019 \ Community \ MSBuild \ Current \ Bin \ amd64 \ MSBuild.
exe "PolicyRecordingBot.sln / t: Publish / p: DeployOnBuild = true / p: Configuration = Release
build passes and I get
"Publishing process has completed.
Build succeeded."
Deployment to Azure fails, .azurePubxml file is ignored

Comment: Are you using Azure WebApp Windows or Linux or Docker?

Comment: windows 10 & visual studio 2019  and win 10 in azure deploy

Comment: I mean what type of Azure WebApp you are using?

Comment: WorkerRole - Worker Role is any role in Azure that runs applications and services level tasks, which generally do not require IIS. In Worker Roles, IIS is not installed by default. They are mainly used to perform supporting background processes along with Web Roles and do tasks such as automatically compressing uploaded images, run scripts when something changes in the database, get new messages from queue and process and more.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify your `azure.pubxml` file under your command.

use this:

```
xxx\msbuild.exe PolicyRecordingBot.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:Configuration=Release -p/PublishProfile=xxx\xxx.pubxml(the full name of the pubxml file under your project folder)
```

Comment: i type : "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe" PolicyRecordingBot.sln /t:Publish /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:Configuration=Release /p:PublishProfile=PolicyRecordingBot\Profiles\tec-stageProduction.azurePubxml and i get :  " Publishing process has completed. Build succeeded."  but nothing is deployed in azure itself

Comment: already another result has not yet figured out - now an error appears and writes "VBCSCCompiler.exe - Fatal error"

Comment: That is not enough info for us to test. You could add `-v:detailed` additionally to get the detailed log. Just as a test, please close any vs Instances, shut down any msbuild.exe,csccompile.exe by task manager. Then run developer command prompt as Administrator, delete `bin` and `obj` folder of the project, and then try the command again.

Comment: sorry to put this project aside for now and tackle others, but this still needs to be done, and so I deleted the contents of the bin & obj directory, closed VS and ran the command  - 

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe" PolicyRecordingBot.sln /t:Publish /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:Configuration=Release /p:PublishProfile=\PolicyRecordingBot\Profiles\dev-powowProduction.azurePubxml -v:detailed

Comment: and i got this 

Build FAILED.

Comment: C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.202\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.CrossTargeting.targets(27,5): error NETSDK1129: The 'Publish' target is not supported without specifying a target framework.

Comment: The current project targ
ets multiple frameworks, you must specify the framework for the published application. [C:\Users\creater\Repos\ms-policy-bot\SharpBot\Samples\Common\Sample.Common\Sample.Common.csproj]